# Sets Without a Minimal Element (Axiom of Foundation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I’m trying to move from an initial appreciation of Cantor’s arguments concerning infinite sets to a more rigorous, axiom-based understanding. I’m having trouble with axiom 8, the Axiom of Foundation or Regularity, in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, however. This axiom is explained as saying that every non-empty set has a minimal member, where “minimal” means “does not contain a proper sub-set of the set”.
The other discussions I’ve seen here focus on avoiding infinite descending chains of sets, but it seems straightforward to construct non-descending counter-examples to the axiom.
In a set where the nth member is the set of positive integers starting with value n, for example,

i.e. {{1, 2, 3, 4, …}, {2, 3, 4, 5, …}, {3, 4, 5, 6, …}, …}

every member contains the next member (and all subsequent members) as a proper subset.
Isn’t this true of every set whose members are either infinite series repeated with progressively later starting values, as above, or infinitely sub-divided sets? (E.g. the set of integers contains the set of even numbers, which contains the set of multiples of 4, and so on.)
If not, why not?

Comment: Here minimality is with respect to $\in$, not to $\subseteq$.

Comment: No element of that set contains a proper subset of the set. Or, indeed, any subset of the set: in particular, every element of that set is a *set* of numbers, whereas every element of any element of that set is a number, so the intersection of your set with any of its elements is empty.

Comment: "Proper" should be "nonempty."

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214408/the-real-numbers-and-the-axiom-of-foundation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regularity is focusing on $\in$, not $\subseteq$.

---

First, let me focus on what we're trying to do. Intuitively, what we want to prevent is the situation $$\color{red}{a\ni b\ni c\ni d\ni e\ni ...}$$ we're perfectly happy with $$a\supseteq b\supseteq c\supseteq d\supseteq e\supseteq ...$$

In the example you give, we *don't* have a descending $\in$-sequence since $\{2,3,4,...\}\not\in\{1,2,3,4,...\}$; what you have is a descending $\subseteq$-sequence, which isn't what we're worried about.

---

That's clear enough, but in my experience (and I think this is the situation here) the confusion arises because of the odd *phrasing* of the axiom of regularity.

Regularity says:

> For every nonempty set $X$, there is some $m\in X$ such that $m\cap X=\emptyset$.

Note that I wrote "$m\cap X=\emptyset$" instead of "$m$ contains no nonempty subset of $X$" - I think the latter is more confusing *(especially because it means "contains" in the sense of $\supseteq$, not $\ni$!)*. Considering your example, *any* of the elements of the set work as $m$: e.g. $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ works, since none of the elements of this are also elements of your set.

Comment: So, we are not happy with $a\supset b \supset c \supset d \supset e \supset ...$ too, right?

Comment: @lockedscope No, **that's** fine: a descending subset chain is different from a descending elementhood chain. That's exactly what the beginning of my answer says.

Comment: so we know that everything is set in ZFC, then subsetness and elementhood should not make any difference?

Comment: @lockedscope Not at all. For example, $\emptyset$ is a subset of itself but not an element of itself. In any set theory the relations $\subset$ and $\in$ are entirely different.

Comment: So, why then, for axiom of regularity here(https://www.math.brown.edu/~res/INF/handout1.pdf) they used $\subset$ instead of $\in$ ? "Given any nonempty subset S, there exists
an element T ⊂ S such that T ∩ S = ∅."

Comment: @lockedscope Well, note that that axiom is very different from "There is no infinite descending $\subset$-chain" - it's not phrased in terms of chains at all! It turns out that even though $\subset$ is used there, it's really a statement about $\in$, and you'll see this after playing around with it for a bit (e.g. see how it prevents an infinite descending $\in$-sequence and convince yourself that it doesn't apply to an infinite descending $\subset$-sequence).

Comment: So, is it fine to think that usage of $\subset$ instead of $\in$ in that context is equivalent? So, is it just about context?

Answer (score 0):

`every member contains the next member (and all subsequent members) as a proper subset.` yes, but the axiom says that there is minimal element with respect to $∈$, here you have that any element is minimal with respect to $∈$, non with respect to $⊆$ ($\{1,2,3,\ldots\}⊇\{2,3,\ldots\}$ but $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}∌\{2,3,\ldots\}$)

Comment: Thanks for these replies. I can’t (can’t yet?) read the more formal ones (e.g. I hadn’t encountered the sideways hook symbol with a line under it, which I don’t know how to type), but the common theme seems to be that elements of sets are not the same thing as sets of elements. So, for example, {1,2} and {1,2,3} have a non-empty intersection because they share elements 1 and 2, not because they both contain {1,2}. Is that, crudely and intuitively, about right? Or am I still missing the point?